# Problem getting LinkedIn access token

Tags: c#, oauth, linkedin-api

I am getting this error during getting Access Token of linkedin, The remote server returned an error:

> (401) Unauthorized. consumer,requst
>   token,verifier contains valid values

```
 TokenResponse accessTokenResponse = OAuthAuthorizationService.GetAccessToken(
                    consumer,
                    "https://api.linkedin.com/uas/oauth/accessToken",
                    "http://api.linkedin.com",
                    requestToken,
                    verifier,
                    HttpMethodType.Post);
```

Answer (score 2):

The 401 Unauthorized error can also appear immediately after login which is an indication that the web site received your user name and password but found something about them to be invalid, so check all parameters.

Answer (score 1):

Bilal, you better search on the LinkedIn Developer network for similar posts, I found this one:

http://developer.linkedin.com/thread/1230